How to search field's in a MongoDB Schema which has Reference to another Schema?
I want to search product with its name in below DOC Schema. But the products are stored as reference to another Product Schema with _id. Below is the code -
DOC Schema
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Product from "./Product";

const DocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  address: [
    {
      region: { type: String },
      country: { type: String },
      plantlocation: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  products: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Product",
    },
  ],
});

const Doc = mongoose.models.Doc || mongoose.model("Doc", DocSchema);
export default Doc;


Product Schema

import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  address: [
    {
      region: { type: String },
      country: { type: String },
      plantlocation: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  installCapacity: [
    {
      year: { type: Date },
      quantity: { type: Number },
    },
  ],
});

const Product =
  mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
export default Product;



My API

import Doc from "@/models/Doc";
import connectToMongo from "@/middleware/db";
import catchAsyncErrors from "@/middleware/catchAsyncErrors";
import ErrorHandler from "@/utils/errorhandler";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import ApiFeatures from "@/utils/apiFeatures";
import Product from "@/models/Product";

type DataType = {
  docs?: object;
  success?: boolean;
  message?: string;
  error?: {};
};

const handler = catchAsyncErrors(
  async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<DataType>) => {
    if (req.method != "POST") {
      return res.status(405).json({ success: false, message: "Bad Request" });
    } else {
      try {
        const apiFeatures = new ApiFeatures(
          Doc.find(),
          req.body.query
        ).search(); // Search Class

        const docs = await apiFeatures.query;
        if (!docs || docs.length <= 0) {
          return res
            .status(404)
            .json({ success: false, message: "Docs not found" });
        }
        res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "Doc data fetched successfully",
          docs,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return new ErrorHandler("Internal Server Error", 500);
      }
    }
  }
);

export default connectToMongo(handler);



MY APIFeature Class

class ApiFeatures {
  query: any;
  queryStr: any;
  constructor(query: any, queryStr: any = "") {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryStr = queryStr;
  }
  /**
   * Builds a search query based on provided criteria
   * @returns this (for method chaining)
   */

  search() {
    let keyword: any =
      this.queryStr.product || this.queryStr.company || this.queryStr.region
        ? {
            $or: [],
          }
        : {};

    if (this.queryStr.product) {
      keyword.$or.push({
        "products.name": {
          $regex: this.queryStr.product,
          $options: "i",
        },
      });
    }

    if (this.queryStr.company) {
      keyword.$or.push({
        name: { $regex: this.queryStr.company, $options: "i" },
      });
    }

    if (this.queryStr.region) {
      keyword.$or.push({
        "address.region": {
          $regex: this.queryStr.region,
          $options: "i",
        },
      });
    }
    this.query = this.query.find(keyword);
    return this;
  }
}

export default ApiFeatures;


I want to search inside DOC Schema with product name I am making a search API using Model.find() method but it fails to find the 'name' field with product ID in DOC schema.
Can some one help me, I want to search Products based on product name in DOC Schema.
Thank You.
I tried Doc.find({// My query }).populate('products') but it simply fetch all products or returns 404 not found.

You can't filter parent documents based on the property of child referenced documents. By that I mean you won't be able to filter Doc documents by searching on products.name. That's because populate is done after searching parent docs so products array just contains ObjectIds  at the point of query matching. Populate is a convenience method. You can however use an aggregation and search by products.name and only return Docs that contain a match for products.name.

To populate you can use like this
await DOC.find().populate("products", "")

either this,
await DOC.find().populate({path: "products", select: ""})

